# Why local variables go missing in Python exec while running bytecode?

Tags: python, bytecode, cpython, python-exec

I've built a function called `foo` to alter a function's code at bytecode level and execute it before returning to regular function execution flow.

```py
import sys
from types import CodeType


def foo():
    frame = sys._getframe(1) # get main's frame

    main_code: CodeType = do_something(frame.f_code) # modify function code

    # copy globals & locals
    main_globals: dict = frame.f_globals.copy()
    main_locals: dict = frame.f_locals.copy()

    # execute altered bytecode before returning to regular code
    exec(main_code, main_globals, main_locals)

    return

def main():
    bar: list = []

    # run altered code
    foo()

    # return to regular code
    bar.append(0)

    return bar

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Though, there is a problem with the evaluation of the local variable during `exec`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Pedro\main.py", line 31, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\Pedro\main.py", line 23, in main
    foo()
  File "C:\Users\Pedro\main.py", line 15, in foo
    exec(main_code, main_globals, main_locals)
  File "C:\Users\Pedro\main.py", line 26, in main
    bar.append(0)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'bar' referenced before assignment
```

If I print `main_locals` before the call to `exec` it shows exactly the same contents as if it was done before calling `foo`. I wonder if it has to do with any of the `frame.f_code.co_*` arguments passed to the `CodeType` constructor. They are pretty much the same, except for the actual bytecode `frame.f_code.co_code`, to which I made a few operations.

I need help to understand why the evaluation of the code under these globals and locals fail to reference `main`'s local variables.

**Note:** I'm pretty sure that the changes made to `main`'s bytecode prevent the process from going into unwanted recursion.

**Edit:** As asked in the comments, the basic behaviour of `do_something` can be resumed to remove all of `main`'s code before call to `foo`. Some additional steps would involve applying changes to local variables i.e. `bar`.

```py
import copy
import dis

## dump opcodes into global scope
globals().update(dis.opmap)

NULL = 0

def do_something(f_code) -> CodeType:
    bytecode = f_code.co_code
    f_consts = copy.deepcopy(f_code.co_consts)

    for i in range(0, len(bytecode), 2):
        cmd, arg = bytecode[i], bytecode[i+1]
        # watch for the first occurence of calling 'foo'
        if cmd == LOAD_GLOBAL and f_code.co_names[arg] == 'foo':
            break # use 'i' variable later
    else:
        raise NameError('foo is not defined.')

    f_bytelist = list(bytecode)

    f_bytelist[i:i+4] = [
        NOP, NULL,                ## LOAD
        LOAD_CONST, len(f_consts) ## CALL
        # Constant 'None' will be added to 'f_consts'
        ]

    f_bytelist[-2:] = [NOP, NULL] # 'main' function RETURN

    # This piece of code removes all code before
    # calling 'foo' (except for JUMP_ABSOLUTE) so
    # it can be usend inside while loops.
    null_code = [True] * i
    j = i + 2
    while j < len(f_bytelist):
        if j >= i:
            cmd, arg = f_bytelist[j], f_bytelist[j+1]
            if cmd == JUMP_ABSOLUTE and arg < i and null_code[arg]:
                j = arg
            else:
                j += 2
        else:
            null_code[j] = False
            j += 2
    else:
        for j in range(0, i, 2):
            if null_code[j]:
                f_bytelist[j:j+2] = [NOP, NULL] # skip instruction
            else:
                continue    
    
    f_bytecode = bytes(f_bytelist)
    f_consts = f_consts + (None,) ## Add constant to return

    return CodeType(
            f_code.co_argcount,
            f_code.co_kwonlyargcount, 
            f_code.co_posonlyargcount, # Remove this if Python < 3.8
            f_code.co_nlocals,
            f_code.co_stacksize,
            f_code.co_flags,
            f_bytecode,
            f_consts,
            f_code.co_names,
            f_code.co_varnames,
            f_code.co_filename,
            f_code.co_name,
            f_code.co_firstlineno,
            f_code.co_lnotab,
            f_code.co_freevars,
            f_code.co_cellvars
            )
```

Comment: i think we are going to have to see `do_something(frame.f_code)`

Comment: Yes, the issue is almost certainly in the function you didn't show; that is by far the most important part of how your program actually works, surely? Please edit to include a [mcve].

Comment: I just added it below. I did not include it before due to its extent and because i was thinking that variable evaluation depended only in the scope defined by `exec`'s parameters.

Comment: Can you add the necessary `import` statements? The code still can't be run as shown (we're missing the `copy` module and something that gives lots of bytecode constants). Anyway, my minimally informed guess is that this has to do with `LOAD_FAST` bytecodes not using dictionaries for locals and globals, but using a separate sequential bit of memory that gives much better performance. I think when you run exec with two arguments, you get the equivalent of a code run in a class body, not the equivalent of a function body, like you want.

Comment: The `LOAD_FAST` hypotesis is very interesting. I will dive further into this. Maybe, there is something to do with the `f_code.co_lnotab` byte sequence. I haven't understood it yet but it's some sort of lookup table. I've included aditional code.